# Copying form fields with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use the following jQuery plugin to add additional form fields:

http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html

The problem is that it does add additional form fields but does not create form names. If I submit this form only the last field will be submitted. How do I add unique name to each created form field?

Comment: Hmm, the way it works doesn't seem particularly useful, except unless it expects you to use name="key[]" so it sends an array of response.

Comment: You say 'but does not create form names', well, the plugin does not claim to *create* things in the added markup; the element that you copy should already contain what you need, because it only creates clones.

Comment: Yes, I understand, I can add name, value, id, class, etc. I just was not sure how to modify name value for copied fields.

Comment: If you use brackets you don't need to modify the names. Guess you already know this.

Answer (score 1):

Since it copies the element (here the form field), you can use `<input name="phone[]" type="text"/>` as the original field.

Comment: Although the examples don't show this, I would bet this is how it's meant to be used, since that just seems to make sense. Otherwise, you'd have to check for the presence of `$_POST[$key] ... $_POST[$key.2] ... $_POST[$key.3] ... $_POST[$key.4]`.

Comment: Yes, the examples are not so helpful, and the author has taken that for granted (and failed to use it himself).